# Search Replace Multiple

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I recently updated a website where over 1000 links were broken. I've created a spreadsheet with Column A being

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column> = REPLACE (
post_content,
```

the old links in Column B, the new links in Column C, and a **)** in Column D. Thus I get:

```
UPDATE wp_jreviews_content SET jr_additionallinks = REPLACE (jr_additionallinks,    '<old link>',   '<new link>')
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin and it works fine except I can only do one at a time. Is there any way can update all the links at once so I'm not left doing it one at a time?

Comment: If there's a pattern to the old link vs new link, you can just do an update statement with the new pattern and not set a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try to add a **;** at the end of each statement.

Answer (score 0):

Semi colon. Duh. Why didn't that come up in my searches before I posted? Sheesh.